# How do I avoid Generic Object Initialization

Tags: java

I have a program in which there is a farm and different types of animals which can be spawned from those farms.

When `new Sheep()` or `new Cow()` is called, an animal is placed onto the field, and when `generate()` is called on the farm, it creates an animal of a type specified.

Something like this:

```
public abstract class Animal {
    public static Arraylist<Animal> allAnimals = new Arraylist<>();
    public Point pos;
    public boolean eatsGrass;

    public Animal(Point p) {
        // Spawn animal onto the field
        allAnimals.add(this);
        this.pos = p;
    }
}

public class Sheep extends Animal {
    public Sheep(Point p) {
        super(p);
        // Run specific Sheep-spawning code
        eatsGrass = true;
    }
}

public class Farm<T extends Animal> {
    public void generate() {
        // Do something here to spawn T
        // Of course, new T(); doesn't work and in general
        // generic object initialization methods are ugly
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Farm f = new Farm<Sheep>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        f.generate();
        // Should create 100 sheep
    }
}
```

I'm not asking how to initialize a Generic object, there's lots of help available for that. I am, however, aware that there are usually better ways to lay out your code to avoid situations in which you might desire to initialize a Generic object.

How would I change/add to this code so that I no longer require Generic Initialization? I've researched the factory pattern, but I'm not sure that helps me in this situation.

Comment: Why is it the `Farm`s responsibility to create the `Sheep`?

Comment: A common pattern **is** to provide some kind of factory mechanism, even if it's as simple as a lambda/method reference: `Farm f = new Farm(Sheep::new)`.

Comment: New sheep are born there, so I thought it made sense for the farm to create them? Correct me if there's a better way of doing it though, I'm still quite new to Java

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Do you know of anywhere I could go to further research that sort of mechanism? I've never seen `::` used before :P

Comment: @Oberdiah - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html.  (Note this is a feature of Java 8+.)

Comment: Don't add animals to `allAnimals` in the constructor. Have the code invoking the constructor add things into a list. Mutable static state like that can get problematic quickly; plus, you are leaking instances before they are fully initialized. `allAnimals` belongs better to the `Farm`, because it is the `Farm` that creates them.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth It's working out really well, but what do I do if the farm wants to access some method or property of the animal, like its color? I can't exactly do supplier.get().color, because that creates a new instance of the animal, which is exactly what I was trying to avoid in the first place.

Comment: You could use a memoized supplier.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth that still involves creating the animal before I can get its color though, which isn't ideal, because I need to show the name of the animal on the front of the Farm even before any Sheep have been created.

Comment: If you need a property from an object, that implies that it needs to exist! So it almost sounds like you need an object/class that represents the concept of "i will create a sheep on demand, and its name is 'sheep'". So literally a factory object.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth That's exactly what I need. I just don't want to make an animal-making object for every type of animal.
I've just ended up with a class that has a static function that takes in a string and outputs that type of animal, but it feels really unwieldy.
At the moment when I add a new Animal I have to manually pop over to the factory and add in a line with that animal's initializer. It just feels like extraneous code, that's all.